# Modifying a Python file object without writing a new file

Tags: python, file, python-2.7, elementtree

I'd like to be able to add a line at the beginning and a line at the end of an xml file object, and then parse the object with ElementTree.

I could read the file, then write the file back out with the new lines, then read it back in and parse it, but it seems dumb to reread the file.

Isn't it possible to modify this file object in place?

Comment: Why do you want to do this? Maybe there's a better way. E.g., how about instead creating a new iterator, something like `itertools.chain([first], fileobject, [last])`?

Comment: You can use [`StringIO`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stringio.html) to create a file-like object without having to actually create a file.

Comment: @tobias_k *Why would you want to do this?* The file isn't valid xml without the two lines, and adding the lines makes it valid. I wouldn't mind creating a new iterator: I would be happy to learn about iterator modification too. Thanks for the pointer to itertools.chain!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you notice that `ElementTree.ElementTree` has also a `fromstring()` method ?

```
lines = open("/path/to/file.xml").readlines()
lines.insert(0, "<something>")
lines.append("</something>")
xml = "".join(lines)
tree = ElementTree.fromstring(xml)
```

Or (more efficient on big files - thanks to chepner):

```
with open("/path/to/file.xml") as source: 
    xml = "".join(itertools.chain(["<something>"], source, ["</something>"]))
# etc...
```

Comment: Aha, so ElementTree can also just parse a string version of the file? That would also be a great solution :) I've just started using ElementTree yesterday.

Comment: Well, it's documented, you know: https://docs.python.org/2/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#parsing-xml

Comment: +1 For long files, I might use would use `xml = "".join(itertools.chain(["<something>"], lines, ["</something>"]))` to avoid the cost of adding an element to the front of the list.

Comment: Or for that matter, you could pass the file object directly to `itertools.chain` so that lines are passed directly to `join` as they are read from the file.

Comment: Dear @brunodesthuilliers : FFR, blithely saying "it's documented" is a pretty aggravating trope among programmers. Naturally it's the first thing I do because I'd rather avoid hearing that tired suggestion. Noticing and remembering every feature and realizing every single alternative method possible to solve a problem is much harder than "it's documented" suggests. Thanks for understanding, and thanks for showing me this alternative: regards.

Comment: @chepner Thank you so much for these suggestions. Are you sure they aren't worth posting as an independent answer, also?

Comment: No, they're just efficiency improvements on bruno's answer.